# How to open popup div after sending xml http request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, http

I am building an extension that should help users use certain site more easily.
Now I am new to AJAX,XML and everything similar so this can be easy question,but I am not sure.

On that website, after clicking on one button, it send xmlhttprequest and after receiving some information it opens a popup div(Displays personas stats etc. and has buttons that are unique for that persona).

Now I wrote the exact same xmlhttprequest that is being sent to server after clicking the button,but after getting the information that is being asked for,it doesn't open anything(which is logical) but I don't know how to open it.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    userz = '76561198364912967',
    url = 'https://www.[WEBSITE-NAME].com/api/v1/getuserinfo/?steam_64='+userz,
    data = 'steam_64=76561198364912967',
    token ='OAuth 3539383833353a313a7b66383738626464332d616536612d343132642d626466342d6136313462366164396139317d';

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("The request and response was successful!");
   }
};
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.setRequestHeader('authorization', token);
request.send(data);
```

Now this is the code and I know that it might not be this language that I am asking for but I think that it is.

[I get same response when clicking on button(that site has) and running my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3zE4.png)

[This is popup div's html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3jDg.png)

[This is how div looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3VsY.png)

Big gradient button has different request data(after clicking it) for each persona that div is opened for.Therefore it has to have something to do with previous request.

The goal is not to make a popup that does nothing, I need to trigger the creation of div that has some functions(like that website makes it)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try using: request.responseText

like this:

```
var res=request.responseText;//answer from application or server
var elm=document.createElement("div");
elm.innerText=res;
document.body.append(elm);
```

Comment: It doesn't do what I need it to do,read comment from "bru02", also I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a popup this should work:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     let mod=document.createElement("DIV");
      document.body.appendChild(mod),mod.className="modal";
      let con=document.createElement("DIV");
      mod.appendChild(con),con.className="modal-content";
      let c=document.createElement("SPAN");
      c.className="close",
        c.innerHTML="&times;",
        c.setAttribute("onclick","this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)"),
        con.appendChild(c);
      let p=document.createElement("P");
      con.appendChild(p),
        p.innerHTML=request.responseText;
   }
};
```

and some CSS:

```
.modal{display:block;position:fixed;z-index:1;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4)}.modal-content{background-color:#fefefe;margin:15% auto;padding:20px;border:1px solid #888;width:80%}.close{color:#aaa;float:right;font-size:28px;font-weight:700}.close:focus,.close:hover{color:#000;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer}
```

[Demo](https://bru02.000webhostapp.com/editor/index.php?id=64835086)

Comment: It does not work. The goal is not to make a popup that does nothing, I need to trigger the creation of div that has some functions(like that website makes it)

Comment: @Ognjen Andric It works with when the URL is "test.html", I changed it to match your questions Url. And if you wan't answers that help, show us the code in TEXT FORM not in a picture, and what should the button make & describe what is 'Displays personas stats etc. '.